# The EncryptByPassPhrase function requires 2 to 4 arguments

Tags: sql, sql-server, encriptación

Tengo una tabla en `sql` con solo dos columnas

```
id int
password varchar(20)
```

Necesito hacer un insert y que el texto que se ingrese en `password` quede `encriptado` en `sql`, tengo esto pero, me marca un erro cerca del  `where`

```
insert into empleado (password) values (ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('holamundo')) where id= 23
```

error:

> The EncryptByPassPhrase function requires 2 to 4 arguments.

Comment: microsoft sql server management

Comment: Además debes por favor agregar el mensaje de error que obtienes

Comment: Como puedes observar en la [propia doc.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/encryptbypassphrase-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) se requieren mas argumentos, por eso te falla

Comment: de que otra manera puedo encriptar solo ese dato, tengo entendido de un sha....

Comment: ¿Ya intentaste agregar lo que haga falta?, consideraría que con eso ya lo debes tener resuelto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La **función** **ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE** debe recibir al menos dos parámetros, pero puede llegar a recibir hasta 4 parámetros, los dos primeros parámetros son obligatorios y los dos últimos opcionales. Esta función devuelve un **varbynary** de **8000 bytes**. Los datos se cifran mediante una **llave de 128 bits** y usando el algoritmo de cifrado **Triple DES(TDES)**. Esta función está disponible desde **SQL Server 2008**.

Para el caso de dos parámetros la sintaxis es la siguiente:

```
EncryptByPassPhrase (clave, textoClaro)
```

El primer parámetro **(clave)** es la frase de contraseña a partir de la cual se genera una **clave simétrica**.

El segundo parámetro **(textoClaro)** sería el texto a cifrar, puede tener un tamaño de hasta **8000 bytes**.

Por lo que la consulta que pones quedará así:

```
Insert into empleado (password) values (ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('clave', 'texto a cifrar'));
```

De esta forma insertamos en el **campo** "**password**" de la **tabla** "**empleado**" el texto '**texto a cifrar**' encriptado, utilizando como llave la que se genera con el **algoritmo** **TDES**  sobre el primer **parámetro** "**clave**"

Para mas información: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs.es-es/blob/live/docs/t-sql/functions/encryptbypassphrase-transact-sql.md

Comment: Al ejecutar la linea me, salta este error 'String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.'

Comment: @Madre, revisa la longitud del campo password, recuerda que cuando se cifra se devuelve un varbinary de 8000 bytes, dale una longitud mayor a la que tienes. Si este campo password tuviese una longitud menor a la que debería tener entonces no se podrá guardar en el la clave encriptada

Comment: y si necesito poner esa encriptación en un id definitivo, el where = 1 como ejemplo, donde lo pondría, ya que me sale un msj  de error cerca del where

Comment: El insert no lleva where, lo que tienes que hacer es aplicar un update sobre el campo que tiene el ID que buscas

Comment: @Madre, seria algo como:               update tabla set campo = EncryptByPassPhrase(x, y) where ID = ...